# Export WhatsApp group chat to PDF

Tags: whatsapp, data-liberation

I have a WhatsApp group conversation that has emotional value so I want to export it, for instance as PDF, to be sure I am able to re-read it in my old days.

WhatsApp has an "Export" feature but it is not usable as it only exports 4 days worth of messages and the 12 latest pictures.

Requirements:

- Export all content, from the first ever message to the today's last message.
- Show images too, within the flow of messages (not as references).
- Gratis
- Ideally PDF, but I am open to other formats. Bonus if the PDF contains full-size pictures so that I can zoom into them.
- Any OS or browser. I can log into WhatsApp from various platforms if necessary to run the export software.